# Forming sub-lists with pre-defined averages from an initial list

Tags: python

Say we have a list `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`, a set of desired averages `a=[2,5,8,11]`, and implicitly 4 groups that we want to form such that each group has a value of 2,5,8, and 11 respectively. Is this essentially a sorting problem? Is there a way to do this without checking each possible combination of sub-lists?

If the above version isn't actually tractable, suppose the goal is instead to form sub-lists by going through the above list in sequence. How does this make things easier?

Comment: where is is your code?

Comment: In a way, your problem is a clustering problem, where you want to form, in the example, 4 clusters with the means reported in the second list. Given the setting, you can use k-means (for a rough idea, look at the related wikipedia page), where the initialized clusters come from the second list. You should provide more details though, e.g., do you have a tolerance for those desired averages?

Comment: @albertoql k-means is a great idea. I don't have a tolerance, I would be able to accept the best fit regardless of how far off it is from the list value in `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the problem, that you have, as suggested in the comment, k-means seems to be an appropriate choice for the algorithm.

You can implement your own version of k-means, or you can start from the implementation provided in [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/), a package providing machine learning techniques, and specifically [`KMeans`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

A possible implementation using `scikit-learn` starting with your example and with the plot is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn.cluster

list1 = np.arange(1,13)
list1_y = np.array([1]*12)
a = np.array([2,5,8,11])
kmeans = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=a.shape[0],n_init=1,init=a.reshape((a.shape[0],1)))
kmeans.fit(list1.reshape((list1.shape[0],1)))
labels = kmeans.labels_
plt.scatter(list1, list1_y, c=labels.astype(np.float))
plt.show()
```

and the result of k-means that found 4 clusters is displayed in the following figure (each data point has a color, identifying the cluster they belong to) :

[image]

There are some aspects that you can look more in depth in order to understand how `sklearn` works:

- The initialization of the class `KMeans`. I included just the relevant parameters, namely the number of clusters, coming from `a`, how many times it should try to perform an initialization, and the means of the initial clusters from `a`. There are other parameters that you can set.
- The call of `fit` function to find the `labels` of each of the data in `list1`.
- The `reshape` for accomodating the dataset for `sklearn`.

For more information about k-means, start looking at the [related wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take some time to look over this and make sure I understand it. Is it possible to replace np.arange(1,13) with some arbitrary imported np.array?

Comment: I took your example, but you can definitely change it, as long as each data point is represented with one single feature (e.g., `list1 = np.array([1, 5, 3, 7, 10, 2, 7, 9]`). If you want to change how a data point is represented, you should change also the structure of the averages to match the number of features representing each data point.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! My other question is, is it possible to get the results of the kmeans as a list or matrix? Is this something I could use pandas for?

Comment: Not directly from the APIs provided in `scikit-learn`, but you can definitely build, for example, a list of lists, according to the labels resulting from kmeans. Each list contains all the data points of a single cluster, and then you can use it with pandas for writing it to a spreadsheet.